# CSS: Using 2 background cover images at the same time

Tags: css, background

I have the following background styles for the container:

```
background-image: url(../img/index/home-5.png), url(../img/index/home-6.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top left, top right;

-moz-background-size:50%;
-webkit-background-size:50%;
background-size:50%;
```

2 images have identical dimensions, which make it easier for them to align. However, the container is fluid, so content can go outside the background, which looks ugly. Is there a method to make both images resize (without loosing dimensions - like in `cover` method)?

Comment: Please add your `html` and `css` code in jsfiddle to give you better solution.

Comment: background-size:cover 50%;